# Inheriting 2 classes in C# - how to handle this 

Tags: asp.net, object, c#-3.0, oop

I need to inherit 2 classes ( a 3rd party classes).

```
(class1) - System.Web.UI.MobileControls.MobileUserControl  
(class2) - PortalModuleBase
```

I have a usercontrol... Normally I inherit "PortalModuleBase" class, but this time I also need to inherit "System.Web.UI.MobileControls.MobileUserControl" in my Usercontrol (.ASCX).

I read in [this](http://blog.vuscode.com/malovicn/archive/2006/10/20/How-to-do-multiple-inheritance-in-C_2300_-_2D00_-Implementation-over-delegation-_2800_IOD_2900_.aspx) article about multiple inheritance with Interface which is the same results when you goolge but I think this doesn't solve my problem....

I read, it's not possible in C#...

But how to workaround this?

thanks,

it's VS2008  -ASP.NET

Comment: The article you provided describes workarounds.

Comment: .NET doesn't support Multiple inheritance. The workaround is to use Interfaces. What do you mean when you say using Interfaces doesn't solve the problem?

Comment: The reason C# doesn't support multiple inheritance is because things get confusing real fast.  Like how to distinguish what property belongs to what class (A,B, or C).

Answer (score 0):

Multiple inheritance is not supported in .net.

Comment: @user472092 Well, your problem seems to be that **want** to inherit from two classes. And you cannot. So you may want to try and explain what you are trying to *achieve*.

Comment: well... as you all know... when you inherit from the the motherclass you get the properties and the functions which is able use in child class.. so defining the class1 as mother class ( x: motherlcass) ... how can I get the properties/functions appearing in the child class too.. how can I get the functions/properties appearing in the child class of the 2nde motherclass?

Comment: @user472092: You're still describing the approach you wanted to take, rather than the bigger goal. You'll need to rethink.

Answer (score 0):

.Net does not support multiple inheritance. You should look to use [interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx) to explicitly implement common behaviour (I.e. the behaviour present in `MobileUserControl`).

There are good reasons for the language not supporting multiple inheritance but it does mean that, in your situation, you will need to do a little more work.